# Mathematics and slavery

Tags: reference-request, math-history

I think that ancient Greek mathematics is a miracle.
Think about Euclid.
Developing mathematical arguments from a small set of axioms is incredibly modern.
And their influence on modern mathematics is huge.
So one naturally wonder why they came up with so great mathematical ideas.
I think one of the main reasons is slavery.
You need *much* free time to do mathematics.
Was there anybody who expressed a similar idea as mine?
Please don't misunderstand me. I'm not advocating slavery.

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. The OP doesn't ask for our opinion. He clearly asks whether or not his idea has been expressed before (presumably, for a wide audience, e.g. in literature). If it was, it is possible to answer the question by simply giving a reference.

Comment: @DanShved You can vote to reopen this question by just clicking "reopen".

Comment: What he is trying to imply (IMHO) is that because they had slaves, they had free time to devote to Mathematics/Research. I am not sure why that should be the case. All you need is *one* Euclid, *one* Pythagoras with sufficient free time. Sure they had students, but even free societies had students. My feeling on this is that almost all researchers do what they do because of an innate inner urge to discover, teach and propagate knowledge. Why else would *we* be here?

Comment: @user44197 oh I see, although I am completely in disagreement with the statement all you need is one Euclid. I believe that living in a place with good opportunities is a lot more important than a super brain. The persons who introduce the super-minds to math are also required.

Comment: @user44197 I think they needed thousands people who had free time to produce one Euclid.

Comment: I don't actually think this is opinion-based, this is just not really relevant to mathematics: this question is really about the history of thought.

Comment: @Newb This is very relevant to math history.

Comment: Yes, but math history is only a specific case of the history of thought/philosophy/intellectual/academic development. To properly answer the question, you need to generalize, and the generalization of this question is not relevant to M.SE.

Comment: When I put [mathematics slavery](http://books.google.com/books?q=mathematics+slavery) into Google Books, the first hit is [a book excerpt](http://books.google.com/books?id=ajGkvOo0egwC&pg=PA19) which says: *It could be argued that the most important institution supporting ancient science was slavery. Greeks and Romans had time for many things because they did not work hard by modern standards and because they had slaves.*

Comment: @MartinSleziak So I'm not the only one.

Comment: Indeed you are not the only one; there are many sources making this suggestion. (I have voted to reopen this question.) But this suggestion is also not well-thought-out, for arguments well-made [here](http://alexandermakedon.com/articles/GreekCulture.html): other cultures at the time (who did not produce mathematics) also had slaves, even many Greek poor people had slaves but no free time, there is no correlation even among Greeks between wealth/slave-owning and mathematics, etc.

Comment: The question is at present a bit imprecise.  The system of slavery used by different civilisations was very varied. The form of what we call slavery in ancient Greece is therefore important in its detail. Athens also had a large network of tribute providers which led to the rise of a class with leisure time.   There are other factors that may be just as important however.

Comment: This question might or might not be appropriate for http://history.stackexchange.com/ but it is not a question about either mathematics or its history.

Comment: More than slavery I think *leisure time* is what makes the huge difference: a people constantly worried by its survival won't have much time to think of abstract stuff. Germans, italians, english, french, etc. had the time for that without having slaves in their lands, though perhaps some of them had them in their dominions.

Comment: You can vote to reopen this thread by just clicking "reopen" if you would like to see other answers which might be equally or more interesting.

Answer (score 11):

The answer yes, such ideas *have* been mentioned before; so yours is not a new thought. However, this is an idea that can too easily be exaggerated.

To some extent, the role of **leisure** in culture, and in mathematics in particular, is well-acknowledged. It even goes all the way back to Aristotle, who himself was wealthy and had the leisure to study. The book ["A History of Greek Mathematics" (1921) by T. L. Heath](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=J-kaAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=Aristotle#v=onepage&q=Aristotle&f=false) has this to say:

> Dealing, at the beginning of the *Metaphysics,* with the evolution of science, Aristotle observes that science was preceded by the arts. [... T]hose arts naturally came first which are directed to supplying the necessities of life, and next came those which look to its amenities. It was only when all such arts had been established that the sciences, which do not aim at supplying the necessities or amenities of life, were in turn discovered, and this happened first in the places where men began to have leisure. This is why the mathematical arts were founded in Egypt; for there the priestly caste was allowed to be at leisure. Aristotle does not here mention Babylon; but, such as it was, Babylonian science also was the monopoly of the priesthood.
>
> It is in fact true, as Gomperz says, that the first steps on the road of scientific inquiry were, so far as we know from history, never accomplished except where the existence of an organized caste of priests and scholars secured the necessary industry, with the equally indispensable continuity of tradition.

Although Heath (and of course Aristotle) doesn’t say this, these remarks also seem to apply (as far as my personal knowledge from reading goes) to the Indian tradition of mathematics. Much of Indian mathematics was done by Jain monks and Brahmins, in both cases communities of people for whom doing mathematics was an acceptable occupation. Note that neither of them was wealthy or owned slaves.

On top of this, mentions of **slavery** specifically in Greek mathematics can also be found in various books:

- Dirk Jan Struik, true to his Marxist principles, says in an article [Some Sociological Problems in the History of Mathematics (p. 379)](http://books.google.com/books?id=eO0i3vqWlOQC&pg=PA379&dq=slavery) that

> “At this point slavery may have played a role [..] by freeing an elite from hard labor and enabling it to discussing politics [..] including art and mathematics [..]. Thus the existence of slavery inside the setting of the *polis* may help to understand how Greek mathematics was founded”.

- He says the same thing in [A Concise History of Mathematics, pages 44 and 56](http://books.google.com/books?id=ECkXB-T2mwIC&pg=PA44&dq=slavery), which Martin Sleziak in his answer has quoted.
- Other authors too: [Tracey Elizabeth Rihll, in "Introduction: Greek Science in Context"](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ajGkvOo0egwC&pg=PA19&dq=slavery)

> It could be argued that the most important institution supporting ancient science was slavery. Greeks and Romans had time for many things because they did not work hard by modern standards and because they had slaves. Slavery was the institution which underwrote science in ancient Greece, in contrast to the redistributive economies of Babylon and Egypt, which enabled kings to employ e.g. astronomer-priests as full-time practitioners of their art. Let us be clear here. I am not suggesting that slavery was a sufficient condition for the emergence and practice of science in antiquity. [...] What I am suggesting is that widespread slavery provided such leisure for many people; that it facilitated widespread participation in activities such as science as well as in politics.

- Also: [some words here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=pN1WaHjvw0sC&pg=PA16&dq=slavery), [here](http://www.sagamorepub.com/files/lookinside/30/pages-pastimes4thed.pdf), the [hypothetical conversation here](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=lSGvPI6LHvwC&pg=PA184&dq=slavery), and so on.

---

I am however sceptical of drawing a correlation between slavery specifically and mathematics specifically. Slavery can buy you some physical comfort and save you from some chores; yet the urge to do mathematics is a function of one’s inner urges and one’s position in society (i.e. having a slave does not automatically give you leisure). Indeed, even rather poor people in Greece or Rome often had slaves. And even with leisure, the fraction of society that is drawn to mathematics (rather than business or politics or hundreds of other things) isn't significant or affected by slavery.

Consider how, in the modern world, no one would credit their mathematical achievement to their owning a washing machine or car. Even though not owning these might indeed take a lot of time away, it is a fact that most people who own these implements accomplish nothing mathematical, and in fact don’t even have copious free time.

See for example this page, [*In Search of Excellence: Historical Roots of Greek Culture* by Alexander Makedon](http://alexandermakedon.com/articles/GreekCulture.html) which points out in response to the slavery idea that:

> “almost all the non-Greek peoples that ancient Greeks came in contact with also maintained slaves, sometimes to a much greater extent than they, and yet not all of them reached the same heights of educational achievement. Even among the Greeks, there is hardly anyone who reached artistic, scientific, or intellectual excellence who is also known to have been either very wealthy, or to have maintained slaves. Instead [...] most of them were either absolutely devoted to their craft (as was Thales of Miletus [..who..] was poor until his historic prediction of the sun's eclipse); or constantly tried to hone their skills [...]. 
>   We may surmise, then, that having slaves, as did the ancient Greeks, is not a sufficient precondition for greatness, just as wealth *alone* is not, although it *can* "buy" both labor and leisure.”

What really seems to help, in the ancient (and even to some extent in the modern) world, is that doing mathematics be seen as a viable occupation: either because you have royal or institutional patronage, or you have some alternative source of income, or you belong to a community where this sort of thing is common (and at least your social status is assured, although not necessarily your financial). Owning slaves is neither necessary nor sufficient for this, and in fact I would say there is no correlation.

Comment: [Consider how, in the modern world, no one would credit their mathematical achievement to their owning a washing machine or car.]

Owning a washing machine or car doesn't buy you free time, because you have to *work* anyway.
On the other hand, if you have slaves, they work for you.

Comment: Owning a washing machine means that I do not have to spend hours each week washing my clothes by hand - that gives me quite a lot of extra free time actually.

Comment: @OldJohn: Isn't that what I said? And yet, if you ask someone the main reason for their mathematical accomplishment, no one would say "my washing machine" — that is just taken as given, plus not everyone with a washing machine does mathematics specifically, plus a lot of them don't even have a lot of free time (the time it saves is used up for something else, like watching TV or needing to work hard to make more money).

Comment: @OldJohn You don't seem to get my point. You have to work anyway. The free time you get by owning a washing machine is nothing compared to that you get by owning slaves who work for you.

Comment: @MakotoKato Don't you know I am retired? I bought my washing machine with my pension.

Comment: @OldJohn [that gives me quite a lot of extra free time actually.] Come on.

Comment: @MakotoKato The problem with the argument about slavery would seem to be this: the Romans used slaves to a great extent and yet seem to have produced no mathematicians that I can find. If you can let me know of any significant mathematical achievements of the Romans, I would be most grateful.

Comment: @OldJohn I'm saying that slavery might be *one* of the main reasons why ancient Greek mathematics was highly developped. I'm not saying it's the only reason.

Comment: @MakotoKato, please replace "mathematics" with "gourmet cooking" in your question to realize how irrelevant this kind of question is.

Comment: @user72694 I'm afraid I don't realize it. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @MakotoKato: there is nothing about your question that's specific to mathematics as opposed to any other purposeful activity, such as "gourmet cooking" or "origami". You could in fact argue that *all* purposeful activities were enhanced by the hateful institution of slavery. However, when a question is posed in such a broad fashion it becomes meaningless.

Answer (score 5):

I'll provide two excerpts from [A Concise History of Mathematics](http://books.google.com/books?id=ECkXB-T2mwIC) by [Dirk Jan Struik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirk_Jan_Struik). Both of them are from the part of the book dealing with ancient Greece. The second quote suggests that slavery was not in all circumstances helpful for the development of science.

[Page 44](http://books.google.com/books?id=ECkXB-T2mwIC&pg=PA44):

> Typical of this new period in Greek history was the increasing wealth of certain sections of the ruling classes combined with equally increased misery and insecurity of the poor. The ruling classes based their material existence more and more upon slavery, which allowed them leisure to cultivate arts and sciences, but made them also more and more averse to all manual work.

[Page 56](http://books.google.com/books?id=ECkXB-T2mwIC&pg=PA56):

> The spread of a slave economy in such a society was fatal to all original scientific work. Slave owners as a class are never interested in technical discoveries, partly because slaves can do all the work cheaply, and partly because they fear to give any tool into the hands of slaves which may sharpen their intelligence. Many members of the ruling class dabbled in the arts and sciences, but this very dabbling
>   promoted mediocrity rather than productive thinking.

Comment: Struik was a committed socialist ("Marxist theoretician", as Wikipedia puts it) and this colors his remarks.  The other source you cited in comments is more straightforward about the possibility that slavery was essential in the development of Greek science.

Comment: @user72694, re-posting the same oppositional comment about the question under each answer is a misuse of MSE comments.  And that Xeroxed comment is incorrect: the question is a reference-request within the scope of this site; it is far from obvious that mathematics is equivalent to all other subjects or that slavery is equivalent to all other sources of leisure time, for this question; and if that were really true, its logical conclusion is not the ridiculous assertion that the question is "not about mathematics or its history" but to state the equivalence as one of the answers.

Comment: @zyx, I deleted the copies. As far as the question is concerned, at least ten editors voted to close it on the grounds that it is not about mathematics, so I don't see how you can claim that such an assertion is "ridiculous". Nobody claimed any kind of equivalence.

Comment: Writing that one can "substitute" gourmet cooking or origami (or any other purposeful activity) for mathematics in this question was a claim of equivalence in the precise sense of *equivalence class*: that Answer(mathematics) = Answer(origami) = Answer(cooking) = Answer(any other purposeful activity). Alternatively, if you did allow the possibility that the those substitutions can affect the Answer, then that whole argument was patently irrelevant.  (Struik's analysis  is an example of an answer that applies to mathematics and does *not* apply to gourmet cooking.)  @user72694

Comment: As to the word *ridiculous*: the question directly refers to "mathematics and its history", is framed in those terms and is tagged [tag:math-history].  So the first problem is to disregard visible facts in favor of a stretched interpretation.  The second ridiculous thing is the specific method of stretching, the idea that if the general form of a question, or of its likely answers, is not super-specific to mathematics, then the question is "not about mathematics".  Besides, a (supposed) lack of specificity would be better addressed in an answer than by shutting down the question.

Comment: To keep the numbers here accurate, there were not "at least ten" users who voted to close the question as not about mathematics.  The number is between $3$ and $7$ (assuming, to help your argument, that only the two close-reasons in the edit history were used).  Of course there are other numbers known here, such as 15 people in support of the question, OP + upvoters, against 14 downvotes, or 6-7 in favor of your "not about mathematics" comments being outnumbered by the 9 people who supported opposite comments under the question, or the currently 5 and 10 upvotes (0 down) on answers. @user72694

Comment: And it is not clear at all that any of the people who Liked the comments on gourmet cooking could or would have defended those arguments.  It's a fun and clever string of words, the kind that often gets MSE comment upvotes just for being witty and entertaining. It is easy to cast a silent vote simply as a matter of preference, such as *disliking* the idea of the question or *enjoying* your comments, but that is very weak evidence that people find the argument in your comments convincing or logically supportable. @user72694